# How to get file descriptor of parent mount namespace?

Tags: linux, mount, manpage, linux-namespaces

In this page: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_ns.2.html

Its mentioned how one can get the file descriptor that refers to the parent namespace of the namespace referred to by `fd`. Its mentioned that it only works for hierarchical namespaces, i.e., user namespace and pid namespace.

However, reading the man page of mount namespaces (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mount_namespaces.7.html), its mentioned that mount namespaces also have a parent and child relationship. This parent-child relationship is important for things like shared-subtrees.

So my question is, is mount namespace not also a hierarchical namespace? I think the answer should be yes, if so, how do I get `fd` of the parent mount namespace similar to how in the first link shared above the code provides `fd` of parent pid/user namespace?